# iPhone(iOS10)とnifty mobile backendとの通信について

Tags: ios, monaca

現在、monacaとnifty mobile backendを利用して開発したアプリがありますが
iOSを10.0.2にアップデートしたところ、nifty mobile backendから
データ取得ができなくなりました。

以下のページを参考にSDKのバージョンを2.1.3にアップデート
してみましたがこれも解決には至りませんでした。
　https://github.com/NIFTYCloud-mbaas/ncmb_js/issues/165

エラー内容は
　Error: cannot GET https://mb.api.cloud.nifty.com:443/2013-09-01/classes/*****

となっております。

どうすれば解決できるでしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

解決方法が載っていました。
参考リンク
http://life-blog.link/programming/post-585

https://github.com/NIFTYCloud-mbaas/UserCommunity/issues/552

Comment: ところでリンク先に載っている解決策は「v2.1.3に更新する」というものですが、質問文を見るとそれは既に試されているようです。